Creating a function in Excel to test for Cell Interior Color that's useable with Conditional Formatting
I ran across a post from 2020 Automate Font Color Depending on Cells Background Color Brightness and found a response by @Tragamor that was 'almost' exactly what I was looking for. Tragamor posted code in reference to creating a function to test if the cell color was dark or not.
Being VERY new to VBA I'm trying to figure out how that function can be made to apply to more than one cell at a time with reference to  using it in conditional formatting. I've attempted to nest other functions within IsDark to reference individual cells such as ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4) but in this case I constantly get #VALUE! errors.
My goal is to find a way to use the function in conditional formatting to select cells based on if the color of the cell is dark and then set the non-fill formatting options to other complimentary colors. Ideally I would like to be able to specify the colors to be used in a separate sheet in the workbook that I call settings. I presently have names defined for colors used in conditional formatting rules and I would like to use the same configuration to dictate the formatting options of the rules in conditional formatting using this function.
However, as written, IsDark can only be set to reference a single cell which has to be manually typed and doesn't support function nesting. The original code from the post if you don't want to follow the link above is as follows:
Public Function IsDark(ByRef Cell As Range) As Boolean
    'If Cell.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim Blue As Long, Green As Long, Red As Long, PerceivedColor As Double
    
    Red = Cell.Interior.Color Mod 256
    Green = Cell.Interior.Color \ 256 Mod 256
    Blue = Cell.Interior.Color \ 65536 Mod 256
    PerceivedColor = 0.299 * (Red ^ 2) + 0.587 * (Green ^ 2) + 0.114 * (Blue ^ 2)
    IsDark = IIf(Sqr(PerceivedColor) > 127.5, False, True)
End Function

Thanks in advance for any help.

How did you try to apply this function in conditional format?

Per the original poster's instructions:
"Building on Pᴇʜ's excellent answer, you can make the text coloring a layer by utilising conditional formatting in addition to the calculated HSP value
You can use the conditional formatting formula =IsDark(A1) {font color = white} in tandem with the following function to effect a similar coloring:"

Then in the Applies to window type the range where you want the function to be active.

Describe the whole problem in detail, because I'm afraid that the difficulty may lie elsewhere. Do you want to reference colors from base or conditional formatting? The quoted function reads colors only from base formatting.

@Black cat - When using conditional formatting using the IsDark() function it will only apply to a single cell when creating a formula to determine which cells to format. e.g. "IsDark(A1)". You can then only apply it to A1 in the "Applies to". It won't allow you to nest any functions.

Then in the Applies to window type the range like this: =$A$1:$C$5

@MGonet - Thanks for your response. Ideally, I'd like it to apply to both base and conditional formatting. What I want to do is use one conditional formatting rule to check to see if the color of a cell is either light or dark and change the color of text based on if the formula evaluates to true. If it doesn't evaluate to true then use a different rule to format the color of the text.
You can ignore the comment about the settings tab as I've worked out how I can accomplish that. Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

@black cat - It doesn't work. If I type IsDark(B1) in cell B1 and that cell has fill color set to back (for example) and is using a font color like light grey I can see the formula outputs TRUE, however when I try to us it as a formula for conditional access it does nothing.

Your function should be in a module for conditional formatting.

If you want to refer to the color of conditionally formatted cells, you should use the DisplayFormat property. Your function might look like this:
Public Function IsDarkCF(ByRef Cell As Range) As Boolean
    If Cell.CountLarge > 1 Then E xit Function
    Dim Blue As Long, Green As Long, Red As Long, PerceivedColor As Double
    Dim col As Long
    col = Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Red = col Mod 256
    Green = col \ 256 Mod 256
    Blue = col \ 65536 Mod 256
    PerceivedColor = 0.299 * (Red ^ 2) + 0.587 * (Green ^ 2) + 0.114 * (Blue ^ 2)
    IsDarkCF = IIf(Sqr(PerceivedColor) > 127.5, False, True)
End Function

This function will work if it is called from VBA, but also, interestingly, it can be used in conditional formatting. However, it will not work when it is called from a sheet as a UDF. In this case, it can only be called indirectly, wrapped in the Evaluate method.
Public Function EIsDarkCF(ByRef Cell As Range) As Boolean
    EIsDarkCF = Cell.Parent.Evaluate("IsDarkCF(" & Cell.Address & ")")
End Function

In the image below, I have shown how this function can be used when cells are formatted with a color scale.

